# install rpm packages with rpm

Tags: centos, rpm, jdk

I tried to install `java 1.7` with `rpm` but got this error:

```
#rpm -i jdk-7-linux-x64.rpm. 
    package jdk-2000:1.7.0-fcs.x86_64 is already installed
```

If the package really was installed, then how come I still can't use `java` or `javac` command. Where is the package installed to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `rpm -ql jdk-2000` to see the list of files provided by the package `jdk-2000` (hint: the rest of the package name given is the version and the architecture, so it's optional to provide it).

If it doesn't link `java` or `javac` to `/usr/bin/`, you can just create the symbolic links from `/usr/<wherever>/.../java/` to `/usr/bin/` using the `ln` command with the `-s` (symbolic link) flag.

It's probably already installed because you tried to install it once, tried the command, it didn't work, so you tried to install it again. Either that, or some other package you installed along the way (or some script you copy and pasted from the internet) installed the package for you. If you want to install the **specific version** of Java you have in that RPM, first remove the existing version with `rpm -e jdk-2000` (`-e` stands for "erase").